# Using Kivy, dynamically add items when a button is pressed

Tags: python, kivy

I wrote the following code.
I want to be able to dynamically add as many items as I want when I press the Add Item button.

```
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from kivy.config import Config
Config.set('graphics', 'width', 300)
Config.set('graphics', 'height', 300)

from kivy.lang import Builder
Builder.load_string("""
<AddItemWidget>:
    BoxLayout:
        size: root.size
        orientation: 'vertical'

        RecycleView:
            size_hint: 1.0,1.0

            BoxLayout:
                orientation: 'vertical'

                Button:
                    id: button1
                    text: "Button1"

                Button:
                    id: addButton
                    text: "Add Item"
                    on_press: root.buttonClicked()
""")

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget

from kivy.properties import StringProperty 

class AddItemWidget(Widget):
    text = StringProperty()

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(AddItemWidget, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def buttonClicked(self):
        print("add item test")

class TestApp(App):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(TestApp, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def build(self):
        return AddItemWidget()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

How do I get an element to be added when I click on a button, as in the image below?

[image]

Instead of just adding one, I want to be able to add 100 or 200 depending on how many times I click the button.

I'd like to be able to delete the buttons I've added as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `add_widget()` to add new `Buttons` to your `BoxLayout`, and using `index=1` always adds the new `Button` just above the `Add Item` `Button`. To do that, you need a reference to the `BoxLayout`, and that can be done by adding an `id` to it in your `kv`. Here is a modified version of your code that does that:

```
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from kivy.config import Config
from kivy.uix.button import Button

Config.set('graphics', 'width', 300)
Config.set('graphics', 'height', 300)
Config.set('input', 'mouse', 'mouse,multitouch_on_demand')  # eliminate annoying circle drawing on right click

from kivy.lang import Builder
Builder.load_string("""
<AddItemWidget>:
    BoxLayout:
        size: root.size
        orientation: 'vertical'

        RecycleView:
            size_hint: 1.0,1.0

            BoxLayout:
                id: box
                orientation: 'vertical'

                Button:
                    id: button1
                    text: "Button1"

                Button:
                    id: addButton
                    text: "Add Item"
                    on_press: root.buttonClicked()
""")

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget

from kivy.properties import StringProperty

class RemovableButton(Button):
    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        if touch.button == 'right':
            if self.collide_point(touch.x, touch.y):
                self.parent.remove_widget(self)
                return True
        return super(RemovableButton, self).on_touch_down(touch)


class AddItemWidget(Widget):
    text = StringProperty()

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(AddItemWidget, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.count = 1

    def buttonClicked(self):
        print("add item test")
        self.count += 1
        newButt = RemovableButton(text='Button'+ str(self.count))
        self.ids.box.add_widget(newButt, index=1)


class TestApp(App):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(TestApp, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def build(self):
        return AddItemWidget()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

I have extended `Button` in a `RemovableButton` class and wrote an `on_touch_down()` method that removes the `RemovableButton` on a right click. By adding `RemovableButtons`, the removal is easy. You may want to show a `Popup` that gives the user a chance to change his/her mind about doing a removal.

Comment: Thank you very much! The answer is what I was looking for. But here's something I don't understand: how do I specify an id for Button, or a function when I press it?

Comment: If you are talking about the `id` that you assign in the `kv`, the answer is that you can't. That `id` is not available from the object, even though it looks like it should be an attribute of the object. Why would you want the `id` anyway?

Comment: I wondered if it would be easier to use the ID to remove the button I added, as follows.If there's another good way to remove, that's still fine.　`newButt = RemovableButton(text='Button'+ str(self.count),id="button"+str(self.count))
  newButt.bind(on_press=self.buttonClickedRemove(self.count))`