# How to remove a dynamically added BoxLayout in Kivy

Tags: python, kivy

I've asked in past questions [how to add and remove buttons dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61745788/how-to-remove-dynamically-added-items-in-kivy/61748851#61748851).

I want to know how to dynamically delete BoxLayout with Python's Kivy.

Here is my code.

```
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from kivy.config import Config
from kivy.uix.button import Button

Config.set('graphics', 'width', 300)
Config.set('graphics', 'height', 300)
Config.set('input', 'mouse', 'mouse,multitouch_on_demand')  # eliminate annoying circle drawing on right click

    from kivy.lang import Builder
    Builder.load_string("""
    <AddItemWidget>:
        BoxLayout:
            size: root.size
            orientation: 'vertical'

            RecycleView:
                size_hint: 1.0,1.0

                BoxLayout:
                    id: box
                    orientation: 'vertical'

                    Button:
                        id: addButton
                        text: "Add Item"
                        on_press: root.buttonClicked()
    """)

    from kivy.app import App
    from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
    from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
    from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

    from kivy.properties import StringProperty

    class RemovableButton(Button):
        def on_touch_down(self, touch):
            if touch.button == 'right':
                if self.collide_point(touch.x, touch.y):
                    self.parent.remove_widget(self)
                    return True
            return super(RemovableButton, self).on_touch_down(touch)


    class AddItemWidget(Widget):
        def __init__(self, **kwargs):
            super(AddItemWidget, self).__init__(**kwargs)
            self.count = 0

        def buttonClicked(self):
            self.count += 1
            boxLayout = BoxLayout()
            textinput = TextInput(text='Hello world'+str(self.count),size_hint_x=0.8)
            deleteButton = RemovableButton(text='×',size_hint_x=0.2)
            boxLayout.add_widget(deleteButton, index=1)
            boxLayout.add_widget(textinput, index=1)
            self.ids.box.add_widget(boxLayout, index=1)
            deleteButton.bind(on_release=boxLayout.remove_widget)

    class TestApp(App):
        def __init__(self, **kwargs):
            super(TestApp, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        def build(self):
            return AddItemWidget()

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        TestApp().run()
```

When the above code is executed, GUI will be launched and a line will be added by pressing the "Add Item" button.

I want to remove the line, so with the "x" button, as in the image below.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a little different than your other example.
For this, you need to use a different function to do the removing.

You also have to import `partial` like this: `from functools import partial`

And here is the changed `AddItemWidget` class:

```py
class AddItemWidget(Widget):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(AddItemWidget, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.count = 0

    def buttonClicked(self):
        self.count += 1
        boxLayout = BoxLayout()
        textinput = TextInput(text='Hello world'+str(self.count),size_hint_x=0.8)
        deleteButton = RemovableButton(text='×',size_hint_x=0.2)
        boxLayout.add_widget(deleteButton, index=1)
        boxLayout.add_widget(textinput, index=1)
        self.ids.box.add_widget(boxLayout, index=1)
        deleteButton.bind(on_release=partial(self.remove_btn, boxLayout))  # change this

    def remove_btn(self, boxLayout, *args):  # and add this
        self.ids.box.remove_widget(boxLayout)
```